# RENAME Excel worksheets dynamiccaly using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 50 workbooks each with two tabs. I want to rename the first worksheet with the same name that of the workbook name.
I know how to to this when there is only one worksheet tab in the workbook.
But It does not work with multiple tabs.
How can I use VBA to dynamically rename worksheets that is same name as workbook name?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As @FreeMan said. When you'll be updating your question, please provide us with this info : **1)** Are the workbooks in one folder? **2)** How did you approach the renaming before (what does not work)? **3)** What result you want to achieve? Addin-button, one-time-macro,...?

Answer (score 0):

This will rename a worksheet to have the same name as the workbook it is in:

```
Worksheets(1).Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

If there are several workbooks and you want to rename the first worksheet in each automatically, you could build a loop around this statement that opens each workbook and then runs the line of code above.